# Can optional foreign key cause trouble in the long term?

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key

In a nutshell, we have two tables:

> Document 1 (strong entity)
> Document 2 (weak entity)

`Document 1` has many `Document 2` and `Document 2` has only one `Document 1`.

That being said, sometimes we need to insert a `Document 2` into the database but a `Document 1` doesn't always exist and that's causing a foreign key error.

Is it OK if I remove the mandatory foreign key constraint, add a `Document 2` and associate them later, when I finally insert the corresponding `Document 1`?

Will the association still formally be present?
Also, can that cause any trouble in the future, like a stored procedure or a view stop working?

Comment: you could add a "dummy" document in Document1, and use that id when inserting document2 , then update document2 with respective document1  when it exists

Comment: @BobKlimes yeah I'll try this approach first, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it OK if I remove the mandatory foreign key constraint, add a Document 2 and associate them later, when I finally insert the corresponding Document 1?

Technically, this is doable, but obviously it breaks the data integrity between two tables `Document 1` and `Document 2`, that your foreign key helps to enforce

You either have to:

A) add all possible records/values into `Document 1` table beforehand, so by the time you insert a new row into `Document 2`, value already exists at `Document 1`, and foreign key is not violated

or

B) Don't insert values into `Document 2`, which don't exist at `Document 1` yet

If you can't achieve any of above (A or B) - then what's the point of having foreign key at all ?

Comment: Well, you can also disable enforcement of the constraint temporarily, can't you

Comment: @mustaccio right, under "remove the mandatory foreign key constraint ... and associate them later" you can think "disable enforcement of the constraint temporarily"

Comment: Dear @AlekseyVitsko I can't upvote because I need more reputation but I would if I could. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I'm simply responding to the "either - or" statement by pointing out another alternative. Besides, even disabled constraints are useful as they demonstrate the intent.

Comment: A disabled constraint may be exactly what OP is looking for... "Will the association still formally be present?" seems to be of concern, and they seem open to not actually having the foreign key constraint in place. Maybe not of course. One tidbit on that - if you're going this route, it could be worth making the doc 2 id field unique in doc 1 table for some level of constraint, since you're forgoing the key relationship